# How to hide index of users (in JSON) from public?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Right now I have a JS script to autocomplete username input. I'm also using the active_model_serializers gem.
The JS script is pulling the list of users from the index action of the users controller as such:

users_controller.rb

```
def index
 @users = User.all
 render(json: @users, each_serializer: UserSerializer)
end
```

at.js autocomplete

```
$( document ).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
    $(function(){
    $("[data-behavior='autocomplete']").atwho({ at:"@", limit: 5, 'data': "/users.json" });
});
})
```

Of course, when I visit example.com/users it shows me the entire list of users as JSON output. How do I allow my JS script to see this but block it from public view? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a HTML call respond differently...

```
def index
  @users = User.all
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html {
       flash[:error] = "Nope"
       redirect_to root_path
    }
    format.json { 
      render(json: @users, each_serializer: UserSerializer)
    }
  end
end
```